# Compare to Clipboard in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, intellij-idea

I am forced to use Eclipse in a new project, but my heart still longs for IntelliJ which I have been using exclusively since before Eclipse was born.

I am getting used to it, but one feature I really miss is "compare to clipboard".

For example, if you see two similar methods in a class, you can copy one to the clipboard, then compare to the other, and it makes it easy to refactor.

Is there any Eclipse plugin for "Compare to Clipboard"?

Comment: Nobody should be forced to use Eclipse! :)

Comment: Yes Nakib, and good people should never suffer and children should never die, and there should be good will to all men and forever peace on earth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard Eclipse does not have a `Compare to Clipboard` option, but there is an Eclipse plugin which allows you to do that: [AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/).

I just tried it and it seems to be what you are looking for: it adds the option `Compare to Clipboard` to the popup menu of the editor and the file explorer views. Comparison is done either on the selected text or the whole file.

Comment: I have never used IntelliJ, exclusively Eclipse... So I can't really tell whether "compare to clipboard" differs from what I propose but : open your java class, look at the "outline" perspective. There, select the two "very similar" methods, right-click then use "compare With > other element". This will open a dialog with the comparison of your two methods. Isn't that what you were searching for?

Comment: @Kellindil It never occured to me to try that, it's great and also a way to achieve what the OP was looking for! You should put it as an answer!

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen I did not put that as answer since I have no idea what the OP actually expects from the "compare to clipboard" command ;). What I suggest here does not allow inline editing of the methods in the comparison dialog, so might not be what he expects. I'll add a secondary answer in case others might need just the "comparison" bit.

Answer (score 3):

Might not be what you expect to achieve through the *compare to clipboard* command (I do not know my way around IntelliJ), but you can compare two methods together through the outline view too :

- Open the Java class containing your methods
- Select both methods
- Right-click then use *Compare With > Other element...*

This will open a comparison dialog displaying the differences between your two methods. This dialog does not allow inline editing, but it is a great way to spot differences between two similar methods.

Note that you can do the same through the package explorer, thus allowing comparison between methods (or inner classes) of distinct java files. For this, you need to make sure that the Package Explorer does not filter the *Java Members* though. Since I don't really know how to explain that bit other than with images, use the *filters* view menu (through the downward facing arrow at the top right of the package explorer view) : [image: package explorer menu]

and in the dialog that opens, make sure that *Java Member* is unticked. Then you can simply expand a java class to see its members in the package explorer, and compare them together : [image]

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer, and it addresses one use case, although it is a little clunkier than the answer I accepted, because it forces you to locate the two methods in the outline view. Also, it assumes the two methods are in the same class. Also, it assumes we are always comparing class files, where the compare to clipboard is very useful for comparing log output, and other non-class data. But yes, it is a great workaround if you don't feel like installing AnyEdit and you are just comparing methods. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorGrazi It does indeed assume that you are comparing java members, but not only when they are located in the same class, which is why I mentionned that it can be done through the package explorer. I mainly added this as a secondary answer because there are a lot of different comparators in eclipse : for java members, for model elements, for text files, for java classes, for folders... and it is always useful to try the different "compare with" options :). This answer was mainly aimed at others finding your questions, since Katja's indeed the best match for your demand.

Answer (score 2):

Another method, albeit clunky, is to use your version control system's diff tool to do this comparison.  Just replace one set of text with the other, save the file, then use your VCS's change tool to see how your file has changed.  If you are using the Git plugin for Eclipse, the easiest way to do this is to open the Git Staging view, find your file in the list, and double-click it.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe you even suggested that! :)

Comment: I actually do this, but the solution with the plugin seems better, of course.